# How can I make a properly association test using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations

In my application I have a model named **License**. These are the following associations of this model :

```
  # Associations
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :file
```

Then in my spec.rb file I wrote that is expeted to this license belongs_to an User, as follows :

```
describe 'when testing associations' do
    it { is_expected.to belong_to :user }
  end
```

And I received what I was expecting :

> License   when testing associations
> should belong to user required: true

Then I tried to to do the same to the another association :

```
it { is_expected.to has_one_attached :file }
```

And I got the following return :

**1) License when testing associations
Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to has_one_attached :file }

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `has_one_attached' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::License::WhenTestingAssociations:0x00000000086ccf48>
 # ./spec/models/license_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'**
```

Why this happened and how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
has_one_attached
```

it is not an active record association type it related to active storage you still can test as following

```
describe 'Attachment' do
  before do
    subject.
      file.
      attach(
        io: File.open(fixture_path + '/dummy_image.jpg'), 
        filename: 'attachment.jpg', content_type: 'image/jpg'
      )
  end

  it 'is valid  ' do
    expect(subject.file).to be_attached
  end
end
```